# Google Apps Script, MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD will list only .docx

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script

I am using a Google Apps Script to list Word files in a folder, however this will work only for .docx files, not .doc.
Any idea?

```
 var folderID = "ID#"
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);
  // will list only .docx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

If you want to retrieve files with the extension of `.doc`, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD
```

#### To:

```
MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD_LEGACY
```

### Pattern 2:

If you want to retrieve files with the extensions of `.doc` and `.docx`, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);
```

#### To:

```
var files = sourceFolder.searchFiles("mimeType='" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD_LEGACY + "' or mimeType='" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD + "'");
```

### References:

- [Enum MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)
- [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Works as a charme! Thanks

Comment: @Riccardo Thank you, too.